# PHP: Regex To Search And Store For A Random String Between Fixed String

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm working on a PHP application which extracts data from remote server where the data is generated randomly. I'm looking for a regex which would help me to grab the bolded data from this command:

```
$.post('sitelink',{opt:'check_log',args:{aid:**2540**,lid:**7**,oid:**0**,ref: 'https://www.google.com'}},
```

I want to write a regex to store all 3 bolded strings (or numbers) above in 3 separate variables or as array. These numbers are randomly generated.

How do I achieve this? Currently I'm extracting this by splitting the whole document as array and then running for loop 3 times and then searching for a comma to break the loop and so on. I think this is so slow as compared to regex.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `aid:(?P<aid>\d+),lid:(?P<lid>\d+),oid:(?P<oid>\d+)` will capture the 3 numbers in the named groups `aid`, `lid`, and `oid`. [See demo.](http://regex101.com/r/yW9lF2/1)

Answer (score 0):

Provided you put your string to test in a $data variable, you could use preg_match function :

```
preg_match("/aid:\*\*([0-9]+)\*\*/,lid:\*\*([0-9]+)\*\*,oid:\*\*([0-9]+)\*\*/", $data, $matches);
```

your 3 variables are catched by ( ) then stored in $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3].

*Note :* $matches[0] contains the original $data string.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys. I found it. Its a little hacky, but it works for my application.

For string: `$.post('sitelink',{opt:'check_log',args:{aid:2540,lid:7,oid:0,ref: 'https://www.google.com'}},`

```
$contents = explode("$.post('http://bc.vc/fly/ajax.fly.php',{opt:'check_log',args:{", $contentget);
$content = explode(',', $contents[1]);

$aid = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $content[0]), 10);
$lid = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $content[1]), 10);
$oid = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $content[2]), 10);
```